# chrome.tabs.executeScript only working with an alert before it

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I believe this is related to the asynchronous nature of chrome extensions.

This section of my code:

```
   alert(tab.title);
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"document.title = 'test'"});
```

Works fine, but as soon as I remove the alert, it stops working. Is there anything I can do to remove the alert but still have the js injected?

**EDIT: More Code**

tabs is a global array of tab objects.

```
  chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function (tabId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      if (tabs[i].id == tabId) {
        var tab = tabs[i];
        while (i < tabs.length) {//length-1
            tabs[i] = tabs[i+1];
            i++;
        }
        tabs.pop();

        alert(tab.title);//WHY IS THIS NEEDED
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"document.title = document.title.substring(1)"});
        return;
      }
  }
  });
```

I am very confused. Changing it the following solves the problem:

```
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"setTimeout('document.title = document.title.substring(1)',100)"});
```

However, as soon as I change the delay to 50, the script doesn't get executed again. I would prefer not to have to have to make this delay. Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Please post more code.

Comment: Replace `return` with `break`. How do you build `tabs` array?

Comment: Replaced. tabs is built essentially with "chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow". Again, the code works without the alert. Strange!

Comment: Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: You need to provide more code - what you showed doesn't seem to contain errors, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I think more code will only confuse. I've added some info above about how adding a delay of .1 seconds solves the problem. If I'm still stuck after this, I can post some more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a race condition. My best guess would be to change the injected code to execute on onLoad.

Comment: 'chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"window.onload = function(){document.title = document.title.substring(1);};"});' does not work...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone is looking - wrap the chrome.tabs.executeScript method in a timeout.

```
setTimeout(function(){chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"setTimeout('document.title = document.title.substring(1)',100)"});},500);
```

It's certainly not ideal but it gets the job done.